# c# list overwrite issue

Tags: c#, list, gridview

I have some code shown below that writes the values of a `gridview` to a list as shown.
The code does get the correct values but when the second row of the grid is added to the list it overwrites the first row of the list.
Anybody know why this is happening?

**C# Code**

```
 List<Item> lstNewItems = new List<Item>(); // Control Items  
 lstNewItems.Clear();
 Item NewItem = new Item();
 foreach (GridViewRow PendingItemUnderControl in GridViewPendingList.Rows)
 {
    NewItem.Paramater = PendingItemUnderControl.Cells[0].Text.ToLower();
    NewItem.Type = (String)Session["BrowseType"];
    lstNewItems.Add(NewItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating one instance of `Item` class. It happens before your loop, so in reality you are working on the same object. You need to create new instance inside loop (in each iteration):

```
List<Item> lstNewItems = new List<Item>(); // Control Items  
lstNewItems.Clear();

foreach (GridViewRow PendingItemUnderControl in GridViewPendingList.Rows)
{
    Item NewItem = new Item();
    NewItem.Paramater = PendingItemUnderControl.Cells[0].Text.ToLower();
    NewItem.Type = (String)Session["BrowseType"];
    lstNewItems.Add(NewItem);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you keep adding the same object, and you mutate it in each iteration of the loop.

You allocate `NewItem` only once, then you configure and add it to the list. When the item in the list, however, you reconfigure it and add it to the list the second time. Now you have two items configured as the last item. Then you configure it as the third item, and add it again. All three items are configured the same, though: the previous two parameters and types are gone. Once the loop finishes, you have `N` *copies* of the same last item in your list.

Move the `new` inside the loop to fix the problem:

```
foreach (GridViewRow PendingItemUnderControl in GridViewPendingList.Rows)
{
    Item NewItem = new Item();
    ....
}
```

Better yet, make your `Item` *immutable*, and pass it the parameters in the constructor:

```
foreach (GridViewRow PendingItemUnderControl in GridViewPendingList.Rows)
{
    lstNewItems.Add(new Item(
        PendingItemUnderControl.Cells[0].Text.ToLower()
    ,   (String)Session["BrowseType"])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the new `Item` outside your loop, so each time you are updating the same element.

```
foreach (GridViewRow PendingItemUnderControl in GridViewPendingList.Rows)
{
    Item NewItem = new Item(); <------
    NewItem.Paramater = PendingItemUnderControl.Cells[0].Text.ToLower();
    NewItem.Type = (String)Session["BrowseType"];
    lstNewItems.Add(NewItem);

}
```

Move the `new` into the loop